# Why the output of ls is different for the same directory /dev/fd/ based on the method of referencing this directory?

Tags: linux, ls, proc, file-descriptors

```
cd /dev/fd/; ls
```

Gives me output that I expect:

```
0  1  2  255
```

But:

```
ls /dev/fd/
```

Gives different output that I don't expect:

```
0  1  2  3
```

Why? What happens here? What happened to file descriptor 255? What is file descriptor 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd /dev/fd/; ls
```

shows the shell’s file descriptors: `cd` changes to the shell’s file-descriptor directory, and `ls` shows its contents.

```
ls /dev/fd/
```

shows `ls`’s file descriptors. File descriptor 3 is the directory being listed by `ls`:

```
ls -l /dev/fd/
```

will show that it points to `/proc/.../fd`, where `...` is the `ls` process identifier.

It might be easier to understand this if you look at `/dev/fd` itself:

```
ls -ld /dev/fd
```

On Linux, it points to `/proc/self/fd`.

Comment: That's interesting that `cd [path]; ls` and `ls [path]` are in fact not equivalent. Thanks to your answer I just invented a game based on this: you can try to predict ls's process id by trying: `ls /proc/self/task/[guessed id]` :) .